# netplan - how to set up a bridge with LAN and AP?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, networkmanager, bridge, netplan

I'm trying to set up a bridge device consisting of a LAN interface and WLAN interface in AP mode.
Internet is provided by the LAN interface; other devices will connect to WLAN interface to connect to the internet.

My current netplan setup without the wifi interface in the bridge:

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: NetworkManager
  ethernets:
      enp1s0:
          dhcp4: no
  bridges:
      br0:
          dhcp4: no
          interfaces:
              - enp1s0
          addresses:
            - 192.168.1.24/24
          routes:
            - to: default
              via: 192.168.1.1
          nameservers:
            addresses:
              - 192.168.1.1

  wifis:
    wlp2s0:
      dhcp4: no
      addresses: [192.168.2.1/24]
      access-points:
        "my-wifi-network":
           password: "secret"
           mode: ap
```

With the above, wireless clients to this "my-wifi-network" network are getting IPs from 192.168.2.0/24 range and able to access the internet (provided by 192.168.1.1, connected through enp1s0 LAN interface).

I want the wireless clients to get 192.168.1.x IP addresses, so that all devices in the 192.168.1.x can talk to each other.

Comment: If you want wireless clients to participate in the 192.168.1.0/24 network, you will need to bridge your wireless interface with your ethernet interface. Is your question, "how do I configure that using netplan"? Or have you tried that and it didn't work as expected?

Comment: Yes, I've tried that - it doesn't work. I've tried to do it by adding the wifi interface into a bridge and changing its IP to 192.168.1.x network. It's unclear to me how to set this up.

Comment: First observation is that when you create a bridge device you don't normally assign an ip to any device in the bridge so you should be able to simply remove the WiFi IP address.

Comment: I don't see anything obviously acting as a dhcp server on this config. What is allocating the 192.168.2.0/24 addresses?

Comment: i have same issue, in my case i also added iptables rules like `sudo iptables -A FORWARD -i wlan0 -o eth0 -j ACCEPT`, `sudo iptables -A FORWARD -i eth0 -o wlan0 -j ACCEPT` and so on, to forward traffic from all interfaces to each other. My wired bridge works fine from eth1 and eth2. eth0 is connected to my main router. But still devices from APs are not getting ip allocated from main network and not able to communicate with internet at all.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you're a little mixed up between the concepts of a "router" and a "bridge".

When you set it up as a router, you configure separate network segments (IP address blocks) for each device and specify routes between them.  A router is concerned with [layer 4 of the OSI model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_layer).  This is what you have done.  With a router you cannot have IPs on both sides in the same IP range.

When you set it up as a bridge, the packets are transferred from one side of the bridge to the other, irrespective of IP address.  They're actually "routed" by MAC address. A bridge is concerned with [layer 3 of the OSI model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_layer).

So in your configuration you should not allocate an IP address to the WIFI at all and keep DHCP turned off on both ethernet and wifi devices.  However you should enable DHCP on the bridge device as this lets your machine communicate.

You also don't need to specify any routes, IP addresses, or nameservers.

So **in theory** it should look something like this:

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: NetworkManager
  ethernets:
      enp1s0:
          dhcp4: no

  wifis:
    wlp2s0:
      dhcp4: no
      access-points:
        "my-wifi-network":
           password: "secret"
           mode: ap

  bridges:
      br0:
          dhcp4: yes
          interfaces:
              - enp1s0
              - wlp2s0
```

### If you want to configure a static IP etc.

If you don't want to use DHCP to configure your server's IP it's important to understand that once you have setup a bridge, it's the bridge that acts as the device, not the wifi or ethernet.

So if you want to configure static IPs, name servers, ... then do it on the bridge definition, not the ethernet or wifi.

### Does this actually work?

I've not tested the above config.  I see sporadic reports across the internet that there is a bug with netplan where it doesn't work correctly for wifis.  The workaround seems to be to list the ethernet device (`wlp2s0` in your question) under `ethernets` instead of `wifis`.

**Try the above first before you assume the bug.** Many of the reports I've read are quite old and the bug may have been fixed.

Comment: Nope, that does not work - when copied verbatim without any change: root@wifi:/etc/netplan# netplan try
//etc/netplan/01-stack.yaml:19:9: Error in network definition: wlp2s0: Duplicate access point SSID 'my-wifi-network'
        "my-wifi-network":
        ^

Comment: @Tomaz there is no duplicate wlp2s0 in this config, you can see that plainly.  Do you have another file in the same config directory?

Comment: No, no additional config files in /etc/netplan/

Comment: it is a bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/netplan.io/+bug/1809994 bridge should be moved to end of the definition